# Generate automatioque variation for product in woocomerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api, woocommerce-rest-api

i am using woocomerce for selling photos only as products.

i want way to make the site generate automatic other quality for the pic and make them in attribut  like Hight quality Normal qulaity Low quality.

how can i lake that automatic or programmatically to reduce puplish steps ?

i tried a this code but i didn't know how to make id dynamique and when i fix it i get error msg when i try add some product

```
$product_id = 123; // Replace with your product ID

$attributes = array(
    'Color' => array('Red', 'Blue', 'Green'), // Example attribute 'Color' with options
    'Size' => array('Small', 'Medium', 'Large') // Example attribute 'Size' with options
);

// Generate variations
$variations = array();

foreach ($attributes['Color'] as $color) {
    foreach ($attributes['Size'] as $size) {
        $variation = array(
            'regular_price' => '10.00', // Set regular price
            'attributes' => array(
                'Color' => $color,
                'Size' => $size
            )
        );

        $variations[] = $variation;
    }
}

// Update product with variations
update_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes', $attributes);
update_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes_wc_data', array());
update_post_meta($product_id, '_default_attributes', array());
update_post_meta($product_id, '_default_attributes_wc_data', array());
update_post_meta($product_id, '_variation_description', '');
update_post_meta($product_id, '_min_variation_price', '');
update_post_meta($product_id, '_max_variation_price', '');
update_post_meta($product_id, '_min_variation_regular_price', '');
update_post_meta($product_id, '_max_variation_regular_price', '');
update_post_meta($product_id, '_min_variation_sale_price', '');
update_post_meta($product_id, '_max_variation_sale_price', '');
update_post_meta($product_id, '_default_attributes', array());
update_post_meta($product_id, '_default_attributes_wc_data', array());
update_post_meta($product_id, '_product_attributes_wc_data', array());
update_post_meta($product_id, '_variation_description', '');
update_post_meta($product_id, '_min_variation_price', '');
update_post_meta($product_id, '_max_variation_price', '');
update_post_meta($product_id, '_min_variation_regular_price', '');
update_post_meta($product_id, '_max_variation_regular_price', '');
update_post_meta($product_id, '_min_variation_sale_price', '');
update_post_meta($product_id, '_max_variation_sale_price', '');
update_post_meta($product_id, '_variations', $variations);
```